# QGIS: select the next entity in the table

Tags: qgis, shortcuts

I try to find a keyboard shortcut that helps me to select the next entity in the attribute table.

Do you have an idea? I tried `CTRL+SHIFT+]` but it's not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried what [@BERA suggested](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/478550/qgis-select-the-nextt-entity-in-the-table/478553#comment780734_478550) and it works

There's the [plugin Go2NextFeature3](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/Go2NextFeature3/):

> Allows jumping from a feature to another following an attribute order
> This plugin allows to select a layer and jump from a feature to
> another. It's possible to select an attribute of the the layer
> (usually an ID) and follow it. Press "F8" to go to the next feature.
> ...